# SpringCloudStream latest version 3.1.4 StreamBridge autowiring is failing

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I have upgraded the latest spring cloud stream from 3.1.3 to 3.1.4, but getting autowire failed error for StreamBridge.

2021-09-25 13:20:15.567 ERROR 2528 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field streamBridge in com.solace.samples.spring.scs.AtomicProcessor required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

2021-09-25 13:20:15.567 ERROR 2528 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field streamBridge in com.solace.samples.spring.scs.AtomicProcessor required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge' in your configuration.

pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
        <solace-spring-cloud-bom.version>2.1.0</solace-spring-cloud-bom.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

DemoApplication.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import java.util.function.Function;


@SpringBootApplication

public class DemoApplication {

    @Autowired
    StreamBridge streamBridge;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<String, String> uppercase() {
        return v -> v.toUpperCase();
    }

    @Bean
    public String value() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have added the code to reproduce